# How to determine if canceled is pressed in a JavaFX ChoiceDialog

Tags: javafx-8

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736299/find-which-button-is-clicked-in-choice-dialog-in-javafx/32737581#32737581) which shows how to manage this with strings, however I am not sure how to check this with a complex object being passed to the ChoiceDialog

I have the following use case:

```
        ChoiceDialog<MyDTO> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<MyDTO>(null, dtoList);
        dialog.setContentText("Select Type");
        Optional<MyDTO> selected = dialog.showAndWait();

        if(!selected.isPresent() || selected.get().getType().equals(currentValue.getType())){
            //nothing selected
            //Display an error message since nothing was selected or changed.
            return;
        }
```

I would only like to perform the validation if the user selects OK, and not cancel or close the box with the X.  I tried to use the sample, but since my list if not a string, then it will not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show a `ChoiceDialog` with a set of options, but nothing initially selected. If the user hits "OK" without selecting something, you want to inform them that nothing was selected; but if the user hits "Cancel" or closes the dialog, do nothing.

The first thing to note is that passing `null` as the default option to the `ChoiceDialog` constructor seems not to work. As a workaround, use the default constructor and then populate the `items` list.

There's no pretty way I can see to distinguish from an empty result due to the user pressing "OK", and an empty result because the user pressed cancel, etc. (I guess you would make a `ChoiceDialog<Optional<MyDTO>>` and start with the selection being an empty `Optional`. Then `showAndWait()` would return an `Optional<Optional<MyDTO>>` which would be empty if cancel were pressed, but would contain an empty `Optional` if OK were pressed with no selection made.)

Why not disable the OK button until a selection is made? You can do this with

```
dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).
    disableProperty().
    bind(dialog.selectedItemProperty().isNull());
```

Here's an SSCCE for that:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceDialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChoiceDialogTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ObjectProperty<MyDTO> selected = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        Button button = new Button("Make choice");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            List<MyDTO> items = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).
                    mapToObj(i -> new MyDTO("Item "+i, i)).
                    collect(Collectors.toList());

            ChoiceDialog<MyDTO> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<MyDTO>();

            dialog.getItems().addAll(items);

            dialog.getDialogPane().
                lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).
                disableProperty().
                bind(dialog.selectedItemProperty().isNull());

            dialog.showAndWait().ifPresent( choice -> {
                System.out.println(choice + " selected");
                selected.set(choice);               
            });
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(button), 350, 120));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class MyDTO {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public MyDTO(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName() + " ("+getValue()+")";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess where my concern was, in the case the user didn't select anything and hit OK.  Currently my list defaults to the first record in the drop down, but is there ever a case where the choice dialog would have a null value as a potential selection?

Comment: `showAndWait()` returns an [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). See update for handling "no selection".

Comment: I understand how Optionals work.  I am trying to determine the difference between Optional.empty() when OK was pressed (if this is possible) and Optional.empty() when Cancel was pressed.  Or should these two different actions be assumed to be the same?

Comment: Ah, OK. I think I understand the question now: you want a different action if the user doesn't make a selection and presses OK to if the user presses cancel, is that right? I think if you give it a default option then the former can't occur, but if you don't I have to think...

Comment: Yes - that is my question.  I need to understand the difference between the two.  In fact in my case I provide NULL as the default choice, however one is still selected when the Dialog opens, which confused me.  If the user hits OK and nothing is selected, I would want to let them know nothing happened since they clicked OK and would expect something to happen.  However, I don't need to check that if Cancel or Close was selected - which my solution solves, but I don't know if that is needed?  Since I do provide a null default choice, I found it odd something was selected.

Comment: OK, yeah, that's not pretty. Maybe an easier approach is to disable the OK button when nothing is selected?

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to handle that with the standard ChoiceDialog?

Comment: Yeah, see update. I'll also see if I can figure out the "double-nested `Optional` approach" I alluded to

Comment: Well, I can get the functionality for the "double-nested `Optional`", but there's no `cellFactory` for a `ChoiceDialog`(!) so I can't make it look right.

Comment: Thanks - that makes it cleaner forcing the user to select something before allowing them to hit OK.  I think it would be better if the showAndWait() returned the buttonType like other dialogs, since we have the getSelectedItem() method on the dialog, then we wouldn't have to jump through hoops.  But this solution works - well enough to move forward with.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change my code as follows to make it work, based on the link, however I find this extremely poor in the way of a solution - so I am hoping there is a better, more intuitive way than this...

```
    //Ensure a new type is chosen
    Collection<String> list = onlineList.stream().map(dto ->dto.getDisplayName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    ChoiceDialog<String> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<String>(null, list);
    dialog.setContentText("Select Type Type");
    dialog.setResultConverter( ( ButtonType type ) -> {
        ButtonBar.ButtonData data = type == null ? null : type.getButtonData();
        if ( data == ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE ) {
            return "OK";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } );

    Optional<String> selectedType = dialog.showAndWait();

    if(selectedType.isPresent() && "OK".equals(selectedType.get())) {
        String typeName = dialog.getSelectedItem();
        String typeCode = onlineList.stream().filter(dto -> typeName.equals(dto.getTypeName())).findFirst().get().getTypeCode();
        if(!typeCode.equals(currentValue.getTypeCode())) {
            //perform my work since this is a valid transition
        }else {
            //throw an error since the item wasn't changed
            return;
        }
    }
```